# Object recognition methods in OpenCV

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I am using some functions such as color contour tracking and image matching which are already available in OpenCV .. I am trying to identify a pink duck, more specifically the head of the duck, but these two functions don't give me the outcome I am expecting for some reasons such as :

1. the color thing don't always work perfect because the change in the lightning , which accordingly would change the color seen by the camera.
2. when I use the image matching thing, I use one image of the duck which I took from a specific position and it can identify the duck only when he is in that position, but I want to identify it even when I rotate the duck or play around with it.

Does anyone have an ideas about a better way to track a certain object ?

Thank you

Comment: Filter the color channels. If the duck is pink, remove the blue channel for better contrast.

Comment: why is that? Also.. I need some ways to identify the head of the duck .. which couldn't be done only by the color, I should figure out a way to do that.. do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [converting the image](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) into the [hsv colourspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)? This colourspace tries to remove the effects of lighting so might be able to improve your colour-based segmentation.

To identify the head of the duck, once you have identified the duck as a whole you could perhaps identify the orientation (using template matching with a set of templates from different viewpoints, or haar cascades, or ...) and then use the known orientation and an empirical rule to determine where the head is located. For example, if you detect the duck in an upright position within a certain bounding box, the head is assumed to be located in the top third of that bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might just take little more than what OpenCV provides straight forward way.

Given your specific question, you might just want to try shape descriptors of some sort.

Basically, try to take Duck's head's pictures shape from various angles and capture the shapes from it.

Now, you can find a likelihood model (forgive me for not a very accurate term) that can validate the hypothesis that a given captured shape indeed belongs to the class of Duck's head or not. Color can just be an additional feature that might help.

If you are a new person in this field - try catch hold of [Duda and Hart: Pattern Classification](http://as.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471056693.html). This doesn't have solution to find-the-duck-problem but will shape your thinking.